# Would like a reg ex expression to find (RE.FINDALL) words with two vowels[aeiou] every FOURTH word on every other (MULTILINE) string?

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-group

```
 textDoc= 
 Line 1 "'"Here is my Text which 
 Line 2 I now have *starred* the words which i would like accounted for"
 Line 3 I would like the end result to be Lines 3 Words 6.
 Line 4.Python Regular expression **rules** have me trying things that 
 Line 5.I have listed below. All of them are usable but I would like 
 Line 6 To understand how to customize it for **production** to use."""

//desiredoutput = Lines 3, Words 3 
/* This is because the words: starred, rules, and production are on every 
   other line and they contain more than 2 vowels all while being the fourth 
   word on the line.*/
```

I can't seem to put it all together but some regular expression code that I am considering and has worked a litttle bit so far are:

```
enumerate, .split. find.All 

[aeiou],[aeiou]{2},



 textDoc = 
numOfLines = len(textDoc.splitlines())
print(numOfLines)
```

split gets the list of words to a string. my guess is I will need a new string with every fourth word on every other line before I count them to accomplish my desired out put of Lines 3 Words 3

Comment: These arbitrary restrictions surely sound like an assignment. And what is it - exactly or at least two vowels? Text and headline say different things.

Comment: thanks Piinthesky. I realize that this a a complex problem which i need help with, I just wish people were a little more considerate. this is a learning exercise given to me by a friend. Yes at least two vowels sir

Comment: Please don't hide this information in the comments and edit your question instead. I would start with [regex tutorials](https://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs) and test my patterns with [regex101](https://regex101.com/#python). This allows you to see immediately, what patterns like `[aeiou]{2}` detect in your sample text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it can't be done with one regex in python because of backtracking, following solution works with perl regex because uses control verb `(*SKIP)`:

```
(?:[a-z]+(?:(?!\n)[^a-z])+){3}((?=(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z])*[aeiou](?:(?![aeiou])[a-z])*[^a-z](*SKIP)(?!)|)[a-z]+)
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/O1guLH/2)

the closest with python doesn't work because of backtracking

```
(?:[a-z]+(?:(?!\n)[^a-z])+){3}((?=(?:(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z])*[aeiou]){2})[a-z]+)
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/O1guLH/3)